# How to customize Primefaces documentViewer toolbar?

Tags: primefaces, pdf.js, primefaces-extensions

I am using primefaces documentViewer which is based on **mozilla PDF.js: 2.11.338**

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/documentViewer.jsf

and I want to customize the viewer to control which buttons to appear in the toolbar like rotate & print & download only.

I couldn't find any guides about that in primefaces website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no JS Widget for Document Viewer however this can be accomplished easily with a JS function like this.

**Note:** Some buttons like `presentationMode` are special and need to be hidden a little differently.

```js
pdfHideButtons : function() {
    var pdfViewer = $("#YourDivId");
    if (pdfViewer) {
        $(pdfViewer.contents().find("#openFile")).hide();
        $(pdfViewer.contents().find("#viewBookmark")).hide();
    }
}
```

Then on your page add this code to basically hide the buttons after the page loads.

```xml
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setTimeout(function(){ pdfHideButtons(); }, 1000);
        });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but adding your pdfHideButtons JS code results in `Uncaught SyntaxError: Functions statements require a function name`.
So I changed it to `function pdfHideButtons() { ... }` and added your 2nd JS code to my page.
These results to `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function` in `pdfviewer.html.xhtml:403` (
`$(document).ready(function () { ... );`

Comment: The `Uncaught TypeError` disappears, when adding the call to `pdfHideButtons()` at the end of my page. Nevertheless `window.frames[0].PDFViewerApplication` results in `pdfViewer undefined`

Comment: I updated my answer you have to find the PDF Viewer main DIV ID and use Jquery like above