# How to Hide/Disable Primefaces Media Download and Print Button

Tags: primefaces

[image: As given in http://www.primefaces.org:8080/showcase/ui/multimedia/media.xhtml?jfwid=25c8e. We can show pdf file using primefaces media. How can we hide/disable download button.]

As given in http://www.primefaces.org:8080/showcase/ui/multimedia/media.xhtml?jfwid=25c8e. We can show pdf file using primefaces media. How can we hide/disable download button.

Comment: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/documentViewer.jsf this gives you a bit more to work with

Comment: Yes and with PF DocumentViewer  you can use this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71868795/how-to-customize-primefaces-documentviewer-toolbar